# Uploading file without multipart/form-data (server to server)

Tags: node.js, rest, post, file-upload, multipartform-data

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695287/256400 , I get the feeling that **multipart/form-data** is needed to upload file from browser to server. But if my use case is to upload file from server to server shouldn't it work if I put the **Content-Type** as **application/octet-stream** or even specific types like **image/png**

I was experimenting with this on a node.js server and used [fs.readFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) to get the file content and used a REST library to do HTTP POST. But I am a bit confused on the encoding to be used when reading the file. Be default fs.readFile returns Buffer object. I was tempted to use **binary** But documentation [here says](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) it's binary is deprecated in favor of Buffer Objects. What would be the correct approach here to read the content of a file and upload? Can this be done without **multipart/form-data**

Comment: Why do you need to specify the encoding? Could you update your question with your source code?

Comment: @npcode you are right.I didn't need to specify any encoding and I was able to work directly with Buffer object and I got this working. I am now using request npm module which takes Buffer objects in body. My confusion arised from the rest client I was using initially which was mojito platforms rest client http://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/api/classes/Y.mojito.lib.REST.html

Answer (score 1):

Answering this since I found what I was looking for.

@npcode is correct. I didn't need to specify any encoding and I was able to work directly with Buffer object and I got it working.

I am now using [request npm module](https://npmjs.org/package/request) which takes Buffer objects in body. My confusion arised from the rest client I was using initially which was [mojito platforms rest client](http://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/api/classes/Y.mojito.lib.REST.html)

Comment: from java script on the browser, if i just attach the file object to the body of the request, are you aware of libraries that will parse the file? i tried with ```multer``` and ```express-fileupload``` and it does not work or i was not able to make it work.

Comment: I need code example for what you are dong