# What is the correct Content-Type for POSTing (only) a file?

Tags: http, post, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

Almost everything I can find suggests using `multipart/form-data`, but [the RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) seems to imply that it is for sending the contents of an HTML "form", and seems specifically suited for sending data that has *multiple parts* (multipart).

Reading a bit about [the `Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) it seems that values like `Content-Type: image/png` (just using the MIME type) are *valid*, and this generally sounds more appropriate to me.

I cannot really find anything that promotes the usage of `Content-Type: <MIME-type>` for POSTing files however.

What is the *correct* approach for this?

Comment: Find one use case of uploading file without multipart/form-data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413709/uploading-file-without-multipart-form-data-server-to-server

Answer (score 2):

multipart types are usually used when doing file uploads from a browser using form POST.

HTTP allows to use any media type with POST; but of course it depends what your server code supports.

Note that [RFC 2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) is obsolete, you should look at [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) instead.

Comment: My question is more towards what if the POST is not coming from a <form>. Or not coming from the *browser*? `multipart/form-data` seems a bit weird if its *single* part and not from a *form*.

I understand its just *headers* and the server can do what it wants with them. Just curious if there are any best practices I am not aware of.