# Posted file has headers added to file content

Tags: node.js, express, post

I am trying to post files to server. It returns 200 OK response, but the content of files is not readable by programs. When I open those in text file, I see boundary and some headers are present in the content of file.

```
File starts with ----------------------------802523244934076832438189
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Test1.png"
Content-Type: image/png 
and Ends with ----------------------------802523244934076832438189--
```

My code is given below:

```
 var formData = {
        file:{
            value: fs.createReadStream('./upload-folder/' + fileName),
            options: {
                filename: fileName,
                contentType: req.body.attachment.mimeType //mimeType from JSON
            }
        }
    };

   var options = {
        url: config.deployment.incidentUrl  + '/attachment?filename=' + fileName,
        method: "POST",
        headers: { ContentType: "application/json"},
        json: true,
        formData: formData
    };

request(options,
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    errorlog.error(`Error Message : PostAttachmentToCSMS : ${error}`);
                }
                else {
                    successlog.info(`Attachment posted for correlation Id: ${corIdFromJira}`);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because using `formData` is mutually exclusive with using `json: true`: the data is *either* `multipart/form-data` encoded *or* JSON-encoded, but it can't be both. The `Content-Type` header also isn't correct (although it's misspelled so technically not the problem).

Try this:

```
var options = {
  url: config.deployment.incidentUrl  + '/attachment?filename=' + fileName,
  method: "POST",
  formData: formData
};
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried this but still the files have extra text in it. :(

Comment: @FaizaIqbal do you control the server-side as well? How is the uploaded data being processed there?

Comment: No unfortunately I do not control server side. I have requested the people managing the server side to check if the request is being processed correctly. But according to them the attachment is added correctly and it is the content in Payload node that contains extra information.

Comment: @FaizaIqbal the extra information is to be expected, it's how file uploads are encoded. However, it sounds like the server isn't actually processing it as a (`multipart/form-data`) file upload, but perhaps even as just a regular `POST` request.

Comment: If that is the case then I can try by posting file buffer as body in regular post request as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413709/uploading-file-without-multipart-form-data-server-to-server

Comment: My case is also similar (Server to Server)

Comment: @FaizaIqbal that might be worth a try. In that case, you probably have to set an explicit `Content-Type` header (to `req.body.attachment.mimeType`) as well.