# PHP not uploading images to database or server?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

Have this html form code on my site to upload images:

```
<input type="file" name="photo">
```

Also have this PHP script to process it:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['postnewstory'])){
    $newusername = $user_data['username'];
    $newemail_address = $user_data['email_address'];
    $newnews_title = $_POST['newnews_title'];
    $newnews_body = $_POST['newnews_body'];
    $newnews_photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
    $newbutton = $_POST['newbutton'];
    $newnews_link = $_POST['newnews_link'];
    $newnews_tags = $_POST['newnews_tags'];

     //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "newsimages/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

        //update the info in database
        mysql_query ("INSERT INTO news (`news_title` ,`news_body` ,`news_photo` ,`news_date` ,`username` ,`news_tags` ,`button`,`news_link`)
        VALUES ('$newnews_title', '$newnews_body', '$newnews_photo', now(), '$newusername', '$newnews_tags', '$newbutton', '$newnews_link');") or die (mysql_error());
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target));


        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>This post was sent!</strong></span></div> ";
} else echo "<strong><font color=red>Update did not work, please try again.</font></strong>";

?>
```

I've tried changing a lot of things, but cannot seem to get it to upload photos the photos or names of the photos? Before I added the upload photo code, and just used:

```
$newnewsphoto = $_POST['photo'];
```

It uploaded the photo name fine, but now I have added the actual upload code for the image itself, it doesn't seem to work? All other information in the form is being uploaded except the image? Anyone have any ideas of what I am doing wrong here? (PS. ERROR CHECKING HAS BEEN LEFT OUT, DOING THAT LAST MINUTE). Thanks!

Comment: I see no error checking in your code? How do you expect to find errors/issues if you aren't looking for them?

Comment: Leaving that out until I have the code working properly.

Comment: Now you can see why you should have them in first. They help you develop your code.

Comment: Have you chmod 777 (read+write) newsimages directory?

Comment: Just changed permissions, still not uploading image or image name though?

Comment: `$_POST` data directly into a query without [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? What could possibly [go wrong](http://bobby-tables.com/)! Unless this is ancient legacy code you should not be using `mysql_query`.

Comment: Do you know why Unit Tests and error handled code is created? It would be useless if it would only be used afterwards (as good as useless). It's to avoid problems during development and for future understanding of the code & maintenance. Last minute error handling is pointless and they are worthless in development companies.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have enctype attribute in your form html like:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: No? I will add that and try.

Comment: That should be the reason

Comment: Yes! Working now! What does that do exactly? Why did my form not work without it? Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I found this answer describing the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695246/why-file-upload-didnt-work-without-enctype

Comment: I concur.  `enctype="multipart/form-data` is code that is being used when you used `POST` so that way the server will recognize it and process it accordingly.

Comment: I changed my answer from "do you have.." to "you need to have.." for clarity, for future viewers.