# How to decide which enctype should I use?

Tags: html, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

According to [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) and [Why File Upload didn't work without enctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695246/why-file-upload-didnt-work-without-enctype), I know that if I want to upload a image or file I need to use multipart/form-data because the data can't simply be represented as key/value pairs. But when I upload an image use 'text/plain', I also success. Why this happened? Also what is the difference between 'text/plain' and 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'?

Comment: By definition, text/plain is plain text and cannot possibly contain images. You must have misunderstood something, but the lack of facts in tbe question does not make it possible to tell what. The differences between encoding types are defined in their specifications, and the question “what is the difference between 'text/plain' and 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'?” has the apparent answer “everything; you might better ask if there is anything common between them” (and the answer is “not really”).

Comment: possible duplicate of [method="post" enctype="text/plain" are not compatible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)