# uploading an image with php

Tags: php, html

I am  trying to upload an image with my form data, but I am getting errors.

Inside my form, the lines for the file are:

```
<li id="li_6" >
    <label class="description" for="file">Filename:</label>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_5"><small>Select the image to upload.</small></p> 
    </li>
```

And here is the upload script:

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])) {

            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);

            if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 60000)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
              if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
              } else {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
                if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                } else {
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                  "media/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }
              }
            } else {
              echo "Invalid file";
            }
            $img_url = '/media/uploads/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $type = $_POST['description'];
            $startPrice = $_POST['startPrice'];
            $reservePrice = $_POST['reservePrice'];
            $buyPrice = $_POST['buyPrice'];
```

not too sure whats going wrong. I've looked it over. I mean the code is directly from the manual.. it should work!

however, I am getting this error:

> ```
> > 
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: file
>
> Filename: controllers/user.php
>
> Line Number: 76
> ```

Comment: $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form?

Comment: You should probably make sure `$_FILE["file"]` is set, as well as `$_FILE["file"]["name"]`

Comment: @u_mulder, when I added that just now I got some very strange behavior from the form. It added the link "http://btcbidder.com/insert?title=POSTHER%2C+WIN%21&description=topkekky+nope+i+dont+want+to+sell+this&type=1&startPrice=.01&reservePrice=.05&buyPrice=1&file=15cc_incomplete_data.jpg&form_id=901208&submit=Submit" to my breadcrumbs, which definately don't want to happen

Comment: This two errors are not connected.

Comment: Noted. It is working now. At least, the upload portion. Still having an issue with the SQL insert, but I can probably hammer that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reason for this error is forgetting to set the `enctype` parameter of the `<form>`:

```
<form method="post" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

More info: [Why File Upload didn't work without enctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695246/why-file-upload-didnt-work-without-enctype)

Comment: i was thinking the exact same thing +1