# Php, Jquery file why is $_files[] empty?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an image uploader with php and jquery but i can't get it to work.
My question is
Why is $_FILES['image']; empty?

Heres my code 


Html
index.php

```
 <form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post">
 <input name="image" type="file" id="image" />
 <a href="#" id="uploadforms">Upload</a>
 </form>
 <div id="uploadresult"></div>
```

jQuery
javascript.js

```
  function uploadimages(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../ajax/upload.php',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      data: new FormData(this),
       success: function (data) {
         $("#uploadresult").html(data);
       },
    });
  }
  $("#uploadforms").click(function(){
    uploadimages();
  });
```

Php
Upload.php

```
 <?php
 if(!empty($_FILES['image'])) {
     echo "Upload image";
 }
 else{
     echo "Error";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: not a duplicate. The answer below is the correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form 
like this

```
 <form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

For more info click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695246/why-file-upload-didnt-work-without-enctype) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Update:

Pass form from function call

```
 $("#uploadforms").click(function(){
    var form = $('form')[0]; //access form obj
    uploadimages(form);
  });
```

And access it in function as

```
function uploadimages(formObj){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../ajax/upload.php',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      data: new FormData(formObj), //changes here
       success: function (data) {
         $("#uploadresult").html(data);
       },
    });
  }
```

Comment: Even with this it's still not working, $file[] is still empty

Comment: Thanks! this helped!