# How do you post and get unique names of the post names?

Tags: php

I was trying to catch the names of this array and then I can sanitize it afterward.  I am just not sure how to use $_REQUEST to catch each 'files(#number)' name that comes through.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title></title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       </head>
       <body>
          <form action="upload.php">
             File: <input type="file" name="files1" multiple="multiple"/><br/>
             File: <input type="file" name="files2" multiple="multiple"/><br/>
             File: <input type="file" name="files3" multiple="multiple"/><br/>
             File: <input type="file" name="files4" multiple="multiple"/><br/>
             <input type="submit">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

upload.php

```
    if ($_REQUEST) {
 // my problem is right here to catch the numbers of 'files'
       foreach ($_REQUEST['files'] as $key => $value) {
          echo $key . '-->' . $value . '<br/>';
       }
    } else {
       echo 'error';
    }



    print '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    print '</pre>';
```

Output because of print_r($_REQUEST) :

```
Array
(
  [files1] => focus48.png
  [files2] => focus48.png
  [files3] => focus48.png
  [files4] => focus48.png
)
```

Comment: file handling requires a post method/retrieval and a valid enctype.

Comment: With SQL you can count and use a for loop, but with a post I am not sure how to handle an array.  Should I make a specific id with the number to add to the name?['name']['id']

Comment: If you are going to use the `multiple` attribute, you only need ONE `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"/>` Note the use of `name="files[]"`

Comment: youir question seems to be growing as we go. that was never mentioned in the original question. If you're wanting to insert in db, then you'll need to post the code for that.

Comment: Maybe [The manual would be a good place to start your adventure with File Uploading in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: This also might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695246/why-file-upload-didnt-work-without-enctype

Comment: I am not worried about database input right now...  just posting an array... so file[] would be the way to go.....  but how can I pull through a specific number?  hidden inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each file input in this form you can have a hidden input that has your number as an array.  You don't need the id=number for the file input, but I left them for your reference.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <title></title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
       <body>
          <form action="upload.php">
             File: <input type="file" name="files[]" id="1" multiple="multiple"/><br/>
            <input name='file_id' value='1' type='hidden' />

             File: <input type="file" name="files[]" id="2"  multiple="multiple"/><br/>
            <input name='file_id' value='2' type='hidden' />

             File: <input type="file" name="files[]" id="3"  multiple="multiple"/><br/>
            <input name='file_id' value='3' type='hidden' />

             File: <input type="file" name="files[]" id="4"  multiple="multiple"/><br/>
            <input name='file_id' value='4' type='hidden' />

             <input type="submit">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Here is how you get the numbers with a hidden array of numbers (arrays start with 0):

```
            if ($_REQUEST) {
       foreach ($_REQUEST['files'] as $key => $value) {
          echo $key . '-->' . $value . '<br/>';
       }
    } else {
       echo 'error';
    }



    print '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    print '</pre>';

     $file_id = $_POST['file_id'];
     echo $file_id;
```

Output:

```
0-->file.txt
1-->file.txt
2-->file.txt
3-->file.txt

Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => file.txt
            [1] => file.txt
            [2] => file.txt
            [3] => file.txt
        )

    [file_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```